# Removing extra verts after boolean operation

Tags: topology, boolean-modifier

is there any option for easy clean up after using boolean mod? Removing this extra verts take to much time.

Ofc Merge by Distance is already used.

[image]

Comment: You can try a X > Limited Dissolve but it may dissolve some edges that you want to keep